# is there a way to serve a different file name from what it appears on server?

Tags: php

I have a system that holds files (attachments) for certain table rows. that means that the file names could be the same some times. i am trying to find a way to store the files in a way i can later on look for the row id, file name or file id and serve that file to download.

i had the following ideas.

1. for each row i will create a folder, in each of the row folder i will create another folder with the file id, and then inside that hold the file. now the issue with that would be handling the directories and sometimes permissions could also be an issue.
2. (i like this method more) have 1 folder with all the files, the file names will be composed of the row id, file id, and file name.

My question is lets say i used method 2 and the file name is something like: `12212.18.this is file name.jpeg`

is there a way for me to serve this file just as :this is file name.jpeg
?

If there's a 3/4 methods you can think of that's better. would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: you can pass it though a php script and change the file name

Comment: how through a php script i am working with php for some times now cant think of a way to do so.

Comment: See this solution: http://serverfault.com/a/316817/88886 -- you will need to change the `Content-type` based on what you are serving. If you just use the default `application/octet-stream` then it will force a file download for all types of files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PHP to ope/read the file and then push it to the browser with whatever name you want.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="your_file_name.jpg');
```

You'll probably need to set other headers - e.g. Content-Type - so best to read up @ https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php.

Comment: so basically to stream it ?

Comment: i think i get it, basically i'll create a page that takes the filename and then use content-disposition to server the real file.. right ?

Answer (score 0):

The [Content-Disposition header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) will let you do that. But this is assuming that you want to offer files for users to download and save on their hard drives. If you just want to serve images to include on a webpage, why bother about the file name at all?

Comment: its to save on their HDs.